# Как сделать форму поиска резиновой

Tags: css

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">
    <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Для поиска напишите нужное слово или словосочетание" name="s" id="s" class="findText" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Найти" class="findButton" />
</form>

.findButton {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    margin-left: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.findText {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы findText растягивался в зависимости от экрана, а findButton был с правой стороны и всегда одного размера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/A52X7/

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Придётся следить что-бы 20% от родительского блока было не меньше 50px (цифры можно подгонять). Должно работать везде.

```
.findButton {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    margin-left: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
}

.findText {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Вариант 2. Использовать функцию [calc()](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc) ([поддерживается в современных браузерах](http://caniuse.com/calc), IE до 10 в пролёте, придётся деградировать до первого варианта)

```
.findButton {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    margin-left: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
}

.findText {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    width: calc(100% - 79px);
}
```

79px это 50px на .findButton и ещё 29 на маргины, паддинги и прочие шероховатости (вроде столько нужно)

P.S. Ну и пример, раз-уж так принято http://jsfiddle.net/PZguP/1/